# Making empty <a></a> tags visible or add some text or style with CSS or Javascript or in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am using some raw code and displaying it in a standalone PHP page.

The raw code has anchors which are empty  tags. Like this :

```
<a name="general-example-2.json"></a>

<a name="another-general-example.json"></a>
```

The only constant is that all these anchors have some random 'name'.

How can I make these anchors visible or clickable in any way ?

I have no control over the original raw code, so can't do anything there.

**Option 1 :** Can some CSS / Javascript be used to make these empty  tags visible or show some default image or link text ?

**Option 2** : Can the `<a name=` be rewritten with `<a class="anchor" name=` with a PHP function and it will be much easier to style the anchor ?

I have spent two days grappling with this situation and nothing seems to work. Please help!

**Edit :** Thank you all for suggesting various approached. @Richard Parnaby-King's CSS solution turned out to be just what I needed.

Comment: Show your relevant code please

Comment: You are trying to edit a code that does not belong to u

Comment: An anchor tag references a hyperlink. It needs to surround something (text, image, div, ANY object). Just having an `<a></a>` will do nothing as an anchor is just saying "When the object inside of me is clicked, go to this link". If you want it to just be white space, then use a blank div with a set width/height.

Comment: Could you clarify what output you want to see? Something specific? Also - what css have you tried already?

Comment: What do you mean by "empty tags"? Elements without text?

Comment: The `name` attribute on an anchor tag is Obsolete and should not be used in  html 5, use id instead - these tags should not be clickable - they are just a reference point for an anchor that is clickable (with a href consisting of an internal hash link to that id) to jump to that point in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this which'll work on only empty links (remove the if statement to work on all links).

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = links.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    if(links[i].innerHTML == ""){
      links[i].innerHTML = links[i].getAttribute("name");
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why is the loop going backwards?  I'm curious.  Unrelatedly, my answer also used querySelectorAll instead of getElementsByTagName, yours is a smarter move.

Comment: just to be funky :)

Answer (score 3):

For applying text to all:

```
let els = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for (let i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].innerHTML = "THIS IS AN ANCHOR ELEMENT";
}
```

I don't have much time, and I'm not sure that I understand your question completely, but I sincerely hope this helps.

Comment: This is basically what I was going to suggest as well

Answer (score 2):

In what way do you want the links to be visible?

As a square block:

```css
a {
  display:block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
 }
```

```html
<a name="general-example-2.json"></a>

<a name="another-general-example.json"></a>
```

Using the `name` attribute?

```css
a:after {
  content: attr(name);
}
```

```html
<a name="general-example-2.json"></a>

<a name="another-general-example.json"></a>
```

Note that the html at the moment does not have an `href` attribute, meaning the links won't do anything when clicked on, or change the mouse cursor when you hover over them.

Answer (score 1):

You can style an element by the name attribute and add content via the ::after pseudo class as such (the name needs to be in " in this case because of the . in the name, normally they wouldn't be necessary):

```
a[name="general-example-2.json"] {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 1em;
    background-color: red;
}

a[name="general-example-2.json"]::after {
   content: "Hello";
}
```